# How should I register at facebook to use facebook api for my app without giving my real name?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-accounts

I wish to use Facebook api in my iphone app. and I know I have to register my app in facebook for key and secret.

I have my own facebook account with my real name and all other info.

**However, I don't want to use my personal real account for registering my app.**

How can I create a specific my-app-related account for using the api?

Create a company or brand page account? or something like that?

Anyone can give me some suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know Company/Brand pages don't get their own accounts, you assign existing accounts to administrate them.

Comment: Please allow me to ask: Why do you not want to create the app with your real account? Creating a fake account as already said may lead to unwanted results => Getting your account and App deleted by Facebook...just sayin'..

Comment: Forget it, in order to create a Facebook app you will have to verify your account by providing either a phone number or credit card, both of which are enough for them to find out much more info about you than your real name.

But really, what's with the paranoia? It's not like hundreds of online services don't know lots of stuff about you.

Comment: @ficheck, ok. Please let me ask a question: how can Pulse have a facebook account with the name Pulse? or Flipboard? but not with the founder of those two companies/apps?

Comment: Because it's not a account, it's a Page/Place associated with a real account that is the admin of those pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook requires a **registered "user"** for app administration and key creation. It's just part of how they keep things under control and avoid spam api calls. As for your question, as far as I'm aware the only way to maintain anonymity is to create an 'alias' account and use that as your admin user for your key.

Comment: how can I create an alias account?

Comment: Yes, when I say alias account I mean create a new user and fake your information.

Answer (score 0):

As T0rpedo said, if you don't want your real name there, you have to use a alias.
There is noway out of that.

Comment: ,how can I create an alias account?

Comment: I believe he means just create an account with false details - but I think you'll find this is a breach of the Ts&Cs

Comment: Just create a normal account in a fake name :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you **COULD** buy yourself a prepaid sim card and verify a fake developer account. Actually there is nothing wrong with having a little paranoia, as far as you don't spam us  : ]